# HP Proliant DL380 G3 not booting. Error "1611 fan 7 not present" after changing power supply

Tags: hardware, hp, boot, hp-proliant

I inherited an HP proliant DL380 G3 some years back and it's been working faithfully as a games/web/build server. At some point during the past year where I haven't been using it the power supply failed.

I have since replaced the power supply but now I'm getting the error above when I try to boot the server which I think is very strange because...

Strange things:

1. The fans were in the same configuration (5 fans) that they were in when the system was running perfectly a year ago
2. No matter how I move the fans around the system complains about fan 7 being missing. None of the fan slots seem to correspond to fan 7
3. None of the fans are failing or have amber LEDs. They all shine a bright healthy green.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Any recommendations on what I can do to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The system boards on G3 ProLiant servers [tended to fail in this manner](https://serverfault.com/questions/56728/best-sysadmin-wtf/279460#279460): the fan sensors tended to go bad. Most of my G3 servers died near 5 or 6 years of service.

It's an 11 year-old system. If you absolutely want another, [pay $50 for another one on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Servers-/11211/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=dl380%20g3) or replace the system board.